# What is wrong with datetime updating?

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
UPDATE `tasks` SET `column1` = NOW()+29100 WHERE `id` = "237759717"
```

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '20171017139327' for column 'column1' at row 1

```
UPDATE `tasks` SET `column1` = (NOW()+29100) WHERE `id` = "237759717"
```

> 1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

Later:

```
UPDATE `tasks` SET `column1` = NOW()+29100 WHERE `id` = "237759717"
```

> 1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

```
UPDATE `tasks` SET `column1` = (NOW()+28260) WHERE `id` = "237759717"
```

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '20171017139301' for column 'column1' at row 1

I'm working in mysql workbench. data type for column1 is DATETIME;

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id int,
  column1 DATETIME
);
```

Comment: I think it might be better to try using DATE_ADD() for better reliability. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: i believe you want to add seconds to the now() function?? if so you need to use `NOW() + INTERVAL [number] SECOND`

Answer (score 3):

You can't add an integer value to a string. `NOW()` produces as string. In order to comply, MySQL coerces the value of `NOW()` to an integer by replacing characters that are strings (the dashes).

What you're after is `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 29100 SECOND)`; instead of `NOW() + 29100`.